# Cant get elements to show after hiding them using javascript/jquery (Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I am having problems trying to get 2 div tags to show up after hiding them.

I tried using jquery with the .hide() and .show() commands and also plain JavaScript using styles.display ='none'/'block'

However if I hide the div tags I cannot get them to show again.

Below is code I am trying to use at the moment:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#redresize").click(function(){
        $("#redresize").hide();
        $("#redinfo").hide();
      });

     $("#expanddownred").click(function(){
        $("#redinfo").show();
        $("#redresize").show();
      });

    });
    </script>
```

Extras

The code runs fine when using IE however it wont run in Chrome or Opera (Haven't tried Firefox).

Im using dreamweaver with the fluid grid layout (not sure if this might be effecting the code)

Due to dreamweaver im also using the predefined boilerplate.css and respond.min.js

I am also using jquery-1.10.2.js

Below is my full code if it is of any use:

```
   <!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- 
To learn more about the conditional comments around the html tags at the top of the file:
paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Do the following if you're using your customized build of modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/):
* insert the link to your js here
* remove the link below to the html5shiv
* add the "no-js" class to the html tags at the top
* you can also remove the link to respond.min.js if you included the MQ Polyfill in your modernizr build 
-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="scripts/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
    $("#underline").fadeTo(1500, 0.15);
    $("#underline").fadeTo(1500, 1);
    $("#bottomheader").fadeTo(1500, 0.15);
    $("#bottomheader").fadeTo(1500, 1);
    },3000);
}
);
</script>


<!--Control Red Section-->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#redresize").click(function(){
    $("#redresize").hide();
    $("#redinfo").hide();
  });

 $("#expanddownred").click(function(){
    $("#redinfo").show();
    $("#redresize").show();
  });

});
</script>

<script>
function redlambolarge()
{
document.getElementById("largeimageredlambo").style.display = 'block'
document.getElementById("sections").style.display = 'none'
document.getElementById("bottomheader").style.marginTop = '3%'
}
</script>

<script>
function redlambolargeclose()
{
document.getElementById("largeimageredlambo").style.display = 'none'
document.getElementById("sections").style.display = 'block'
document.getElementById("bottomheader").style.marginTop = '0'
}
</script>

<!--Control Blue Section-->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#blueresize").click(function(){
    $("#blueresize").hide();
    $("#blueinfo").hide();
  });

 $("#expanddownblue").click(function(){
    $("#blueinfo").show();
    $("#blueresize").show();
  });

});
</script>

<script>
function bluelambolarge()
{
document.getElementById("largeimagebluelambo").style.display = 'block'
document.getElementById("sections").style.display = 'none'
document.getElementById("bottomheader").style.marginTop = '3%'
}
</script>

<script>
function bluelambolargeclose()
{
document.getElementById("largeimagebluelambo").style.display = 'none'
document.getElementById("sections").style.display = 'block'
document.getElementById("bottomheader").style.marginTop = '0%'
}
</script>

<!--Control orange Section-->

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#orangeresize").click(function(){
    $("#orangeresize").hide();
    $("#orangeinfo").hide();
  });

 $("#expanddownorange").click(function(){
    $("#orangeinfo").show();
    $("#orangeresize").show();
  });

});
</script>

<script>
function orangelambolarge()
{
document.getElementById("largeimageorangelambo").style.display = 'block'
document.getElementById("sections").style.display = 'none'
document.getElementById("bottomheader").style.marginTop = '3%'
}
</script>

<script>
function orangelambolargeclose()
{
document.getElementById("largeimageorangelambo").style.display = 'none'
document.getElementById("sections").style.display = 'block'
document.getElementById("bottomheader").style.marginTop = '0'
}
</script>

<!--End of Scripts-->

</head>

<body background="images/background.jpg">

<div class="gridContainer clearfix">

  <div id="header">Super Cars</div>

  <div id="underline"></div>

  <div id="largeimages">  

    <div id="largeimageredlambo">
        <img src="images/redlambo.jpg">
        <input class="closelambo" type="button" onclick="redlambolargeclose()" value="Close">
    </div>

    <div id="largeimagebluelambo">
        <img src="images/bluelambo.jpg">  
        <input class="closelambo" type="button" onclick="bluelambolargeclose()" value="Close">
    </div>

    <div id="largeimageorangelambo">   
        <img src="images/orangelambo.jpg">
        <input class="closelambo" type="button" onclick="orangelambolargeclose()" value="Close">
    </div>  
  </div>

  <div id="sections">


    <div id="firstsection"> 
      <div id="firstsectiontitle">Red Lamborghini</div> 
        <a href="#" type= "button" onClick="redlambolarge()">
        <img src="images/redlambo.jpg">
        </a> 

      <div id="expanddownred">↓   Information   ↓</div>

      <div id="redinfo">
      <p>This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="redresize">↑  Close  ↑</div>

    </div>


    <div id="secondsection"> 
      <div id="secondsectiontitle">Blue Lamborghini</div>
        <a href="#" type= "button" onClick="bluelambolarge()">
        <img src="images/bluelambo.jpg">  
        </a>

      <div id="expanddownblue">↓   Information  ↓</div>

      <div id="blueinfo">
      <p>This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="blueresize">↑  Close  ↑</div>

    </div>


    <div id="thirdsection">
      <div id="thirdsectiontitle">Orange Lamborghini</div> 
        <a href="#" type= "button" onClick="orangelambolarge()">
        <img src="images/orangelambo.jpg">
        </a>

      <div id="expanddownorange">↓   Information  ↓</div>

      <div id="orangeinfo">
      <p>This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes. This is where the content for the lamborghini goes.</p>
      </div>

      <div id="orangeresize">↑  Close  ↑</div>

    </div>


  </div>

  <div id="bottomheader"></div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Below is also my CSS Code if it helps:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* Simple fluid media
   Note: Fluid media requires that you remove the media's height and width attributes from the HTML
   http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluid-images/ 
*/
img, object, embed, video {
    max-width: 100%;
}
/* IE 6 does not support max-width so default to width 100% */
.ie6 img {
    width:100%;
}

/*
    Dreamweaver Fluid Grid Properties
    ----------------------------------
    dw-num-cols-mobile:     6;
    dw-num-cols-tablet:     12;
    dw-num-cols-desktop:    18;
    dw-gutter-percentage:   15;

    Inspiration from "Responsive Web Design" by Ethan Marcotte 
    http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design

    and Golden Grid System by Joni Korpi
    http://goldengridsystem.com/
*/

body {
    background-color:#999;
}

#largeimageredlambo,
#largeimagebluelambo,
#largeimageorangelambo {
    display:none;
}

/* Mobile Layout: 480px and below. */

.gridContainer {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 88.0434%;
    padding-left: 0.9782%;
    padding-right: 0.9782%;
}

#header {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:36px;
    border-top-left-radius:40px 40px;
    border-top-right-radius:40px 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    /*-moz-border-radius:40px 40px ;
    -webkit-border-radius:40px 40px ;*/

}
#underline,
#bottomheader {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #F00;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    border:thick 2px;
    border-bottom-style:solid;
    border-radius: 80px / 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px ;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px ;
}
#firstsection,
#secondsection,
#thirdsection {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
#firstsectiontitle,
#secondsectiontitle,
#thirdsectiontitle {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:24px;
    background-color:rgba(51,204,102,0.6);
    border-top-left-radius:30px 30px;
    border-top-right-radius:30px 30px;
    /*-moz-border-radius:30px 30px ;
    -webkit-border-radius:30px 30px ;*/
}
#firstsectiontitle:hover,
#secondsectiontitle:hover,
#thirdsectiontitle:hover {
    background-color:rgba(51,255,102,0.6)
}
.closelambo {
    font-size:14px;
    margin-left:40%;
    width:20%;
}
#expanddownred,
#expanddownblue,
#expanddownorange {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color:rgba(51,204,102,0.6);
}
#redinfo,
#blueinfo,
#orangeinfo {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#FFF;
    display:none;
}
#orangeresize,
#blueresize,
#redresize {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:rgba(51,204,102,0.6);
    border-bottom-left-radius:30px 30px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:30px 30px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    display:none;
}


/* Tablet Layout: 481px to 768px. Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 89.0217%;
    padding-left: 0.4891%;
    padding-right: 0.4891%;
}
.closelambo {
    font-size:18px;
}
#header {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#Underline,
#bottomheader {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#firstsection{
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 49.4505%;
    display: block;
}
#secondsection {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 1.0989%;
    width: 49.4505%;
    display: block;
    margin-top:0%;
}
#thirdsection {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25%;
    width: 49.4505%;
    display: block;
    margin-top:0%;
}
#expanddownred,
#expanddownblue,
#expanddownorange {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#redinfo,
#blueinfo,
#orangeinfo {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#orangeresize,
#blueresize,
#redresize {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
}

/* Desktop Layout: 769px to a max of 1232px.  Inherits styles from: Mobile Layout and Tablet Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 769px) {
.gridContainer {
    width: 89.3478%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    padding-left: 0.326%;
    padding-right: 0.326%;
    margin: auto;
}
.closelambo {
    font-size:18px;
}
#header {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#Underline,
#bottomheader {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#firstsection{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 32.8467%;
    display: block;
    margin-top:0%;
}
#secondsection,
#thirdsection{
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0.7299%;
    width: 32.8467%;
    display: block;
    margin-top:0%;
}
#expanddownred,
#expanddownblue,
#expanddownorange {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
#redinfo,
#blueinfo,
#orangeinfo {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
#orangeresize,
#blueresize,
#redresize {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
}
```

Thank You For Having A Look

Comment: It's very hard to read your code. Is a good practice to indent the code.

Comment: have you tried using the chrome debugger to see if the code you have there ever gets executed ?

Comment: not sure what the debugger is however the code seems to activate and run fine on Chrome in the inspect element view however those changes don't appear to have any effect on the actual site running in the browser.

Comment: sorry about the hard to read code (still learning) and thanks for the tip about indenting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#redresize").click(function(){
    $("#redresize").css('display','none');
    $("#redinfo").css('display','none');
  });

 $("#expanddownred").click(function(){
    $("#redinfo").css('display','');
    $("#redresize").css('display','');
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer. Unfortunately it did not work :(    I only seem to be having trouble with it in Chrome and Opera (works in IE)

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me on slightly different conditions, but maybe this'll help you.

Adding stupid bugs is a bad habit of chrome devs (not to mention their unwillingness to correct many old annoying bugs). Opera uses the same engine, btw.
Yesterday I updated chrome and every block with tabs where disblay:none->display:block (show() in your case) was set on document ready rendered with zero dimensions and thus invisible (even without overflow:hidden its contents were invisible).

There are two ways to get things work as intended:
- don't use display:none;(i.e. hide()) hide it, setting height:0 and overflow:hidden 
- wrap showing with setTimeout with 0 time